# How to match ^(d+) in a particular text using regex

Tags: java, regex

For example I have text like below :

case1:

```
(1) Hello, how are you?
```

case2:

```
 Hi. (1) How're you doing?
```

Now I want to match the text which starts with `(\d+)`.

I have tried the following `regex` but nothing is working.
`^[\(\d+\)]`, `^\(\d+\)`.

Comment: Did you use `String#matches()`? In that case use `\(\d+\).*`. Do you want to match case 2 as well? How do you want to match something like `Hi. (1) How're you doing? (2) Well, I'm fine. But I dunno how to match this. (3) done.`?

Comment: In case you still struggling getting it to work update your question adding code snippet, showing us how you actually use the regex matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` are used to match any of the things you specify inside the brackets, and are to be followed by a quantifier.

The second regexp will work: `^\(\d+\)`, so check your code.

Check also so there's no space in front of the first parenthesis, or add `\s*` in front.

EDIT: Also, java can be tricky with escapes depending on if the regexp you type is directly translated to a regexp or is first a string literal. You may need to double escape your escapes.

Comment: Thank you all, this one is working!! I did try this but I don't how I didn't get earlier. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: So, did you need regex to match the words after the number, or just the number? Because `^\(\d+\)` will only match the brackets and the number, but your post says > `I want to match the text which starts with (\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have to escape parenthesis, so `"\\(\\d+\\)"` should match `(1)` in case one and two. Adding `^` as you did `"^\\(\\d+\\)"` will match only case1.

You have to use double back slashes within java string. Consider this

- `"\n"` give you [line break]
- `"\\n"` give you [backslash][n]

Answer (score 0):

> **If you are going to downvote my post, at least comment to tell me WHY it's not useful.**

I believe Java's Regex Engine supports Positive Lookbehind, in which case you can use the following regex:

`(?<=[(][0-9]{1,9999}[)]\s?)\b.*$`

Which matches:

- The literal text `(`
- Any digit `[0-9]`, between 1 and 9999 times `{1,9999}`
- The literal text `)`
- A space, between 0 and 1 times `\s?`
- A word boundary `\b`
- Any character, between 0 and unlimited times `.*`
- The end of a string `$`

Comment: [0-9]{1,9999} will allow you to have 9999 numeric characters. not 0-9999.

Comment: That's intentional. the `java.util.regex` package doesn't allow infinite repetition inside of a lookbehind.

Comment: can you not just use a +, a * or {0,}? (i also missed the word 'times' in your description, and thought you said it was a number between 1 and 9999)

Comment: I never knew that... but then i've never needed an infinite number!